# What Trump meant by the last sentence?

Tags: meaning

This is an excerpt from what Donald Trump said in a 2016 interview with the Miami Herald. I am not sure I understand the last sentence. Could any teacher explain that to me?

> Well, I’m not a big believer in manmade climate change. It could be some impact but I don’t believe it’s a devastating impact.
>
> I am a huge believer in clean water and clean air, crystal water and air. I’m a very big believer in that and we have a lot to do with that, keeping our water clean, keeping our air clean.
>
> But I would say that it goes up and it goes down. I think it’s very much like this over the years. We’ll see what happens. I mean we’ll see what happens. **Maybe you and I even you as young as you are, you won’t be around to see but certainly climate has changed but you used to call it global warming**.

Comment: There are quite a lot of the normal stop-start, and interruptions that occur in transcribed speech. Try to make a paraphrase of the sentence (you could probably break it into several short sentences) [edit] the question to include your paraphrase.

Comment: What does *covfefe* mean? I seldom pay attention to his speeches! ;)

Comment: Translation:  What we're seeing in this so-called "climate change" are the natural cyclic fluctuations of the planet. Human beings have nothing to do with it. These are long cycles, and even as young as you are, you probably won't be alive to see the cycle return to lower temperatures.

Comment: This was omitted from the transcript: And we're going to have a really great theme park, it will be the best theme park, people will envy us all around the world, with saber-tooth tigers, woolly mammoths, giant sloths, you name it. This is in our future.

Comment: Thank you,  Tᴚoɯɐuo. What was omitted that you wrote makes me smile.

Answer (score 1):

Trump has the habit of stopping himself in the middle of the sentence to add remarks that break its structure. It's often helpful to imagine commas and parentheses to help clarify the sentence:

*Maybe you and I (even you, as young as you are) [...] won’t be around to see, but certainly climate has changed, but you used to call it global warming.*